# Get-ChildItem : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Directory'

Tags: powershell

I am getting `Get-ChildItem : *A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Directory'*` error message , below is the script used, kindly help me in finding the issue?

**Script:**

```
Function Clear-ReadOnlyFiles([string]$path)
{
  "Clearing readonly attribute from files in $path"
 New-Variable -Name read_only -Value 1 -Option readonly
 Get-ChildItem -Path $path |
 Where-Object { $_.attributes -match 'readonly' } |
 ForEach-Object {
   $_.attributes = $_.attributes -Bxor $read_only }
}#end Clear-ReadonlyFiles


$ZipCmd     = "{0}\7za.exe" -f $BackupDir
$ZipCmdArgs     = "-sdel"

# Grab Directories in Location
$Directories = Get-ChildItem -Path $BackupDir -Directory

# Cycle Through and Launch 7za to Compress
# Check if Archive Exists - If yes, delete source folder
ForEach ($Directory in $Directories)
{
    $Source  = "{0}\{1}" -f $BackupDir,$Directory.Name
    $Archive = "{0}.7z" -f $Source

    # Clear Read-Only Attribute on Folder
    $SubFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $Directory -Recurse -ReadOnly
    ForEach ($SubFile in $SubFiles) {
        $SubFile.IsReadOnly = $False
    }

    #If ($Directory.IsReadOnly -eq $True) { $Directory.set_IsReadOnly($False) }

    $AllArgs = @('a', $ZipCmdArgs, $Archive, $Source);

    & $ZipCmd $AllArgs
}
```

**Error message:**

```
Get-ChildItem : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Directory'.
At C:\Play\BackupCompress.ps1:35 char:57
+ $Directories = Get-ChildItem -Path $BackupDir -Directory <<<< 
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ChildItem], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

Get-ChildItem : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'ReadOnly'.
At C:\Play\BackupCompress.ps1:45 char:66
+     $SubFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $Directory -Recurse -ReadOnly <<<< 
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ChildItem], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

Property 'IsReadOnly' cannot be found on this object; make sure it exists and is settable.
At C:\Play\BackupCompress.ps1:47 char:18
+         $SubFile. <<<< IsReadOnly = $False
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (IsReadOnly:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that the Directory switch was added in PowerShell 3.0. In older versions you will need to check the PSIsContainer property of each child item, which will be true if the item is a directory:

```
$Directories = Get-ChildItem -Path $BackupDir | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer }
```

Comment: Chirsh, thanks for your reply. how to resolve the 'Readonly' error message? Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path 'C:\play\test' because it does not exist.
At C:\Play\BackupCompress.ps1:36 char:29
+ $Directories = Get-ChildItem <<<<  -Path $BackupDir | ?{ $_.PSIsContainer }
    + CategoryInfo  : ObjectNotFound: (C:\play\test:String) [Get-ChildItem], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommandGet-ChildItem : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'ReadOnly'. At C:\Play\BackupCompress.ps1:45 char:66

Comment: You should be able to use the IsReadOnly property of the child items for this:

`$SubFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $Directory -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.IsReadOnly}`

Answer (score 2):

**-Directory** is a conditional parameter and only works on paths whose provider is "*FileSystem*". It's present on this page: [Get-ChildItem for FileSystem](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847897.aspx), but not on [the generic one](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849800.aspx).

Make sure that the correct provider appears when you type the following:

```
Get-Item $BackupDir | Select-Object -Property PSProvider
```